# MongoDB can multiple fields be added to a single $addToSet?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have:

```
user {
  _id: ObjId(..),
  name: "John Smith",
  computers: ["MSI desktop", "Mac Book"],
  phones: ["Pixel", "Galaxy"]
}
```

In below example, I am trying to find all the distinct values of computers and phones in the aggregation, but as one single field, like so:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, 
            "electronics": {$addToSet: ["$computers", "$phones"]}
        }
    },
])
```

Obviously above threw a error so I'd like to know if there is a way to do it with `$addToSet`.

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple fields. Make the multiple fields as an _object_ (or a sub-document).

Comment: How to do that really depends on what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator to get all the values that appears in any of your arrays :

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, 
            "electronics": {$setUnion: ["$computers", "$phones"]}
        }
    },
])
```

Cannot test it right now, but you must get exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

$unwind + $addToSet + $concatArrays:

```
db.test.insert({  name: "John Smith",
  computers: ["MSI desktop", "Mac Book"],
  phones: ["Pixel", "Galaxy"]
})

db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind:'$computers'},
{$unwind:'$phones'},
{$group: {_id: null, e: {$addToSet: '$computers'}, e2: {$addToSet: '$computers'}}},
{$project:{electronics:{$concatArrays:['$e','$e2']}}},
])


 { "_id" : null, "electronics" : [ "MSI desktop", "Mac Book", "MSI desktop", "Mac Book" ] }
```

Comment: I would recommend concat'ing the arrays first, and then unwind the combined array so that you wind up with fewer intermediate documents.